# Is there a way to export a SVG that's under 'class=' on a website?

Tags: svg

Is there a way to download/export the svg under:

```
<span class="connect-device-list-item__connect-icon spoticon-spotify-connect-16"></span>
```

from https://open.spotify.com ?

[image]

Where I should look to find the SVG code? In a linked file?

I've tried to search in this file liked in the head of  the page:  https://open.scdn.co/static/web-player.981ff160.css
but there are only css color tags like "{color:#404040}".

How I should locate a SVG on a website like this?
I've tried two bookmarklets and they don't work on the page.
Also tried a chrome extension but it doesn't "grab" that svg. Only the logo, a few more svgs.

This is the inspect element:
[image]

Comment: its most probably not an SVG so you can not download a SVG. It is most likely  a font.

Answer (score 1):

That's not an SVG, it is an icon font (which is in reality, the same as any other font).

The `content: "\F1A3"` CSS rule shows us the codepoint of the character in the font itself and `font-family: glue1-spoticon;` gives us the name of the font.

You'll find the font in the "Application" tab of  Chrome's Developer Tools, or you can find a `@font-face` rule somewhere in the CSS (which may or may not be the same CSS file the icon is used in), that defines a font called `glue1-spoticon`; where you'll find the URLs (probably in a few different formats) of the font.

...With all of that said, the font is likely (not that I've checked) a proprietary font that you don't have the rights to use. Just because you can download something, don't assume you have the right to use it yourself.